# What is `: View` in `public function view(): View` in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

In laravel, I found `: View`, but I am not able to understand it completely.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;

class Export implements FromView
{
    

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\View
    */
    public function view(): View
    {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

If someone can explain, then highly appreciated.

Comment: See: https://php.net/language.types.declarations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a PHP [return type declaration](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_returntype_declarations.htm) which specifies the value type that a function should return.

So in your example, the function is defined such that the type of the value it returns is an instance of a class that implements the `Illuminate\Contracts\View` interface. If you try and return a value which does not implement `Illuminate\Contracts\View` then you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

this defines the "Return type declaration" added since PHP 7.0 (This method should return an object having type "View"). moreover PHP throw an error if the returned value cannot be converted into the specified type;